# SQL insert rows between existing records

Tags: sql

I have a table with records corresponding to loans ONLY on the specific dates they are taken out and repaid - i.e., two records per loan.

```
Loans

Loan ID | Month     | Rate  | Action
--------------------------------
1       | 5/1/2000  | 5.50% | New
1       | 9/1/2000  | 6.00% | Closed
2       | 3/1/2000  | 5.25% | New
2       | 5/2/2000  | 5.50% | Closed
```

I have another record with interest rates for every date.

```
Interest rates

Month       | Rate
--------------------
1/1/2000    | 5.00%
2/1/2000    | 5.25%
3/1/2000    | 5.25%
4/1/2000    | 5.25%
5/1/2000    | 5.50%
6/1/2000    | 5.50%
7/1/2000    | 5.50%
8/1/2000    | 6.00%
9/1/2000    | 6.00%
10/1/2000   | 6.50%
```

I would like to insert rows for missing dates in loan table (and corresponding interest rates) between when a given loan is taken out and repaid. Given that the intermediate dates need to be inserted for EVERY loan, I haven't been able to solve this with LEFT JOIN, MERGE, etc.

Expected result:

```
Loan ID | Month     | Rate  | Action
---------------------------------
1       | 5/1/2000  | 5.50% | New
1       | 6/1/2000  | 5.50% | NULL
1       | 7/1/2000  | 5.50% | NULL
1       | 8/1/2000  | 6%    | NULL
1       | 9/1/2000  | 6%    | Closed
2       | 3/1/2000  | 5.25% | New
2       | 4/1/2000  | 5.25% | NULL
2       | 5/1/2000  | 5.50% | Closed
```

Comment: please show some sample data, the expected output and tag the database you are using.

Comment: By improving format question is more readable. And I've changed a bit user explanation, I think it has more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Numbers table is often helpful when you need to generate rows for a sequence of dates.  It is simply a table that contains a large sequence of integers.  You can read about how to create one [here](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) (among other places).  Once you have that in place, you can use a query like this (this is for SQL Server):

```
;with cteLoan as(
select t1.LoanID, min(t1.Month) StartDate, max(t1.Month) EndDate
from Table1 t1
group by t1.LoanID
)

select c.LoanID, dateadd(month, n.Number, c.StartDate) Month, t2.Rate, null Action
from Numbers n
cross join cteLoan c
join Table2 t2 on t2.Month = dateadd(month, n.Number, c.StartDate)
where n.Number >= 0 and n.number < DATEDIFF(month, c.StartDate, c.EndDate) 

union

select t1.LoanID, t1.Month, t1.Rate, t1.Action
from Table1 t1
order by LoanID, Month
```

To insert the results into another table, you should be able to do:

```
insert into Results(LoadID, Month, Rate, Action)
select c.LoanID, dateadd(month, n.Number, c.StartDate) Month, t2.Rate, null Action
from Numbers n
cross join cteLoan c
join Table2 t2 on t2.Month = dateadd(month, n.Number, c.StartDate)
where n.Number >= 0 and n.number < DATEDIFF(month, c.StartDate, c.EndDate) 

union

select t1.LoanID, t1.Month, t1.Rate, t1.Action
from Table1 t1
order by LoanID, Month
```

Comment: Jerrad, your suggestion worked - thank you! But I'm having trouble saving the output as a permanent table. Can you please advise where to place the "SELECT * INTO ..." clause? Thank you.

Comment: I tried the above but am getting the following error:                               Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'Results'. Do I need to create a table called Results first?

Comment: Well you need to create the Results table first.  You can also put `into Results` right after the first `SELECT` to insert into a new table on the fly.  `select c.LoanID, dateadd(month, n.n, c.StartDate) Month, t2.Rate, null Action
into Results ...`

Answer (score 0):

Your designs making that hard and you didn't say what database you are using. Here is a sample for SQL server (query would also work for postgreSQL):

```
DECLARE @loans TABLE
    (
      LoanID INT ,
      [Month] DATETIME ,
      Rate DECIMAL(4, 2) ,
      [Action] VARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT  @loans
        ( LoanID, Month, Rate, Action )
VALUES  ( 1, '5/1/2000', 5.50, 'New    ' ),
        ( 1, '9/1/2000', 6.00, 'Closed ' ),
        ( 2, '3/1/2000', 5.25, 'New    ' ),
        ( 2, '5/2/2000', 5.50, 'Closed ' );


DECLARE @rates TABLE
    (
      Month DATETIME ,
      Rate DECIMAL(4, 2)
    );
INSERT  @rates
        ( Month, Rate )
VALUES  ( '1/1/2000', 5.00 ),
        ( '2/1/2000', 5.25 ),
        ( '3/1/2000', 5.25 ),
        ( '4/1/2000', 5.25 ),
        ( '5/1/2000', 5.50 ),
        ( '6/1/2000', 5.50 ),
        ( '7/1/2000', 5.50 ),
        ( '8/1/2000', 6.00 ),
        ( '9/1/2000', 6.00 ),
        ( '10/1/2000', 6.50 );

WITH    loanStart
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @loans
               WHERE    Action = 'New'
             ),
        loanEnd
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     @loans
               WHERE    Action = 'Closed'
             ),
        loanRanges ( loanId, lStart, lEnd )
          AS ( SELECT   ls.LoanID ,
                        ls.Month ,
                        le.Month
               FROM     loanStart ls
                        INNER JOIN loanEnd le ON ls.LoanID = le.LoanID
             )
    SELECT  lr.loanId ,
            r.Month ,
            r.Rate ,
            COALESCE(ls.Action, le.Action) AS action
    FROM    @rates r
            INNER JOIN loanRanges lr ON r.Month >= lr.lStart
                                        AND r.Month <= lr.lEnd
            LEFT JOIN loanStart ls ON ls.LoanID = lr.loanId
                                      AND YEAR(ls.Month) = YEAR(r.Month)
                                      AND MONTH(ls.Month) = MONTH(r.Month)
            LEFT JOIN loanEnd le ON le.LoanID = lr.loanId
                                    AND YEAR(le.Month) = YEAR(r.Month)
                                    AND MONTH(le.Month) = MONTH(r.Month)
    ORDER BY lr.loanId ,
            r.Month;
```